# Retrieving data by using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get inner join data by using outer join?

**TABLE A**

```
ID   SALES 
-----------
1    100                                  
2    200                                  
3    300
4    400
```

**TABLE B**:

```
  ID   SALES
  -----------
  1    100                                  
  2    200
```

BY USING LEFT JOIN I WANT ONLY MATCHING 2 RECORDS

Desired output:

```
ID  SALES  ID  SALES
--------------------
1   100     1  100
2   200     2  200
```

Comment: Interesting question, but it shows zero effort.  Can you at least show us some table structure?

Comment: A WHERE clause can help you I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #A                             
(ID INT   , SALES     INT)
INSERT INTO     #A VALUES                       
(1,100),                                  
(2,200),                                  
(3,300),
(4,400)

CREATE TABLE #B 
(
ID INT,SALES INT
)
INSERT INTO #B VALUES
(1,100),
(2,200)




SELECT * FROM #A  A  LEFT JOIN 
#B B ON A.ID=B.ID
AND A.SALES=B.SALES
WHERE B.ID IS NOT NULL

OUTPUT

ID  SALES  ID  SALES
1   100     1  100
2   200     2  200
```

Comment: THANKS venkatesh.i think we dont need specify sales. with out sales also we can get it.

Comment: Yes id itself filter null values ..@AVI

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Select A.ID, A.sales, B.ID, B.sales 
from #A 
left join #B on A.ID=B.ID 
where B.ID is not null
```